# credit risk transition matrix

Tags: markov-chains, finance

When using Markov chains it is usually assumed that it has an absorbing state (aka default). I wonder why this is needed? I know that it is not necessary to have a unique stationary distribution, but are there other considerations as well? Besides it is not a valid assumption in practice (Basel2 definition allows cure from default).
Thanks,
B

Comment: To increase the chance that your reader know about Basel 2, add the (finance) tag. The Math.SE crowd is more likely to think of Basel as the birthplace of Euler or Johann Bernoulli.

Comment: "When using markov chains it is usualy assumed that it has an absorbing state" - This is not true in general.